# I want my script to be run automatically whenever an ad appears in Youtube

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I wrote a js query to fast forward a Youtube video:

```
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 16;
```

I have bookmarked this script and whenever an ad comes on Youtube, I press the bookmark which increases the speed of add and then I click the skip button.

Now I want that query to run automatically whenever an ad comes.
I found a way to detect if the ad is playing or not:

```
if (document.querySelector("div.ad-showing")) 
{
    // Ad is active as a video 
    console.log("this is an ad")
}
else 
{
    console.log("the video is playing")
}
```

Is there any way to click SKIP button automatically?

In short I am trying to make a low level ad skipper with whatever knowledge I have. The main task is how to trigger execution of a script based on and event

I can't find the direction as I don't have much knowledge of js so help me out.

I am open to suggestions of other ways of doing the same but keep it simple as I am noob who is trying to play around

THANKS